# Show all points on graph while panning along x axis

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine(God bless the folks behind this) for data that my application is continuously receiving over a socket connection. The point are plotted against time which is my x axis. To achieve a moving graph i am having to remove items from the TimeChart if the count goes beyond 20.

```
timeSeries.add(Float.parseFloat(xAxisData), yAxisData);
if(timeSeries.getItemCount() > 20){
    timeSeries.remove(0);
}
```

So far so good.
But now the problem is that if a user pans through the graph and wants to see some of the older points the graph does not show them. Understandably so because i have already deleted those points from the TimeSeries.

So the question is how to show the older data when i pan through the graph along the X axis?

Is there an alternative way to give a the graph a moving effect other than deleting points from the TimeSeries because i understand if the TimeSeries hold all the point my problem will be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative. Whenever you want the graph to "move", just call the methods below and then do a repaint:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minVisibleValue);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxVisibleValue);
chartView.repaint();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, thanks a ton... You're a wizard. It should have been setXAxisMin and setXAxisMax though, but i got it.